# Is nature symmetric between particles and antiparticles?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

Is nature symmetric with respect to presence of particles? Do we have an antiparticle for every particle thought of? Are there any proven examples where we don't have an antiparticle? And what about antiparticle of a photon (we know it can also behave as a particle)?

Comment: do we discuss symmetry and anti-symmetry only when we have charged particles?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antineutron

Comment: @Dan you mean to say that we also discuss symmetry or anti symmetry based on spin?

Comment: Are you just asking whether every known particle has an antiparticle (and vice-versa)?

Comment: @David yes thats what I am asking

Comment: @ bubble--well, yes, but neutral bosons are their own anti-particles--ie photons and gravitons and likely the Higgs boson.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The anti-particle for any particle is obtained by charge C and parity P conjugation. C is the operation that interchanges positive and negative charges and P is the operation that reflects in a mirror. The combined operation of CP must produce a particle of the same mass. This is a theorem of relativistic quantum field theory due to CPT symmetry. This other particle is either the same particle or an antiparticle with opposite charge and/or chirality.

Some particles such a photons, gluons, Z bosons, pions, Higgs, graviton etc, do not have anti-particles because they are invariant under the CP transformation. You can say that they are their own anti-particle. This can only happen for particles without electric charge and with no chirality.

In principle the QCD color charge is also reversed for an anti-particle. This suggests that a gluon should not be regarded as its own anti-particle, but since colourless states are never seen the distinction cannot really be made in any operational sense.

All known particles which are their own anti-particle are bosons, but it is also possible for a fermion to be its own anti-particle if it is a Majorana spinor rather than a Dirac spinor. No known fermions are of this type (unless neutrinos are Majorana) but they exist in SUSY models.

Observed elementary particles that do have anti-particles include all the quarks and leptons (except possibly the neutrinos) and the charged W bosons. Any composite particle also has an antiparticle made of the anti-particles of its constituents. This can only be its own anti-particle if all its constituents are (e.g. a glueball), or if it is made of particle/anti-particle combinations as is the case for pions.

Comment: Nice reminder on the Majorana spinors.

Comment: if boson is an anti-particle of boson can two bosons stay together or they annihilate ?

Comment: If you put a charged particle and its anti-particle together they can form a bound state. After a short instant they will annihilate, if they don't decay individually first. For example you can combine an electron and a positron to form positronium. Same thing could be done with bosons in principle but there are no good examples. Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, for every known particle there is an anti-particle. But [bosons are their own antiparticle](http://www2.slac.stanford.edu/vvc/theory/antiquarks.html), for example, the $\pi^+$ which is (mostly) composed of an up-quark and a down-antiquark $u\bar{d}$, has as an anti particle the $\pi^- = d\bar{u}$. The antiparticle of the photon is just the photon, while the antiparticle of the $W^+$ is the $W^-$.

Composite particles, such as the hydrogen atom, also have corresponding antiparticles, but not all of them have been observed. So far the heaviest antimatter atom observed is [anti-helium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter#Antihelium), but theoretically, it seems clear that anti-uranium could be produced.

Comment: Not all bosons are their own antiparticle. Only the photon, Z and gluon are.

Comment: To be somewhat pedantic, the heaviest antimatter atom that has been observed is anti-hydrogen. While antimatter *atomic nuclei* of deuterium, tritium, Helium-3, and Helium-4 (aka alpha particle) have been produced, to my knowledge the actual atoms (bound states of the anti-nuclei and positrons) have not yet been observed.

Comment: @Willie: "Anti-Helium Discovered in Relativistic Heavy Ion Collider Experiment" http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/04/110424152441.htm

Comment: @Hans: at the bottom of the news article you cite, you have the [link to the actual journal article](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v473/n7347/full/nature10079.html), whose title is: "Observation of the antimatter helium-4 nucleus". `:-)` I have that particular issue of _Nature_ sitting right next to me on the couch right now (I just read the issue three days ago), so I was pretty sure about what I wrote.

Comment: @Willie; A "helium nuclei" is an atom. If this is news to you, look up the wikipedia definitions of "ion" and "atom".

Comment: @kmm; See the first link given in the post. The $W^{\pm}$ is its own anti-particle. From the point of view of elementary particles, treating the $W^+$ and $W^-$ as two different particles (which therefore have each other as anti-particles) is as iffy as treating the left-handed and right-handed electrons as distinct particles. (I'm hewing to the party line here, this is what is taught. The reason has to do with the definition of "particle" which would make a great question. But I agree with you and consider the $W^+$ and $W^-$ as distinct. I just don't think I should write this in an answer.)

Comment: @Carl: we must be reading the same Wikipedia page differently then. To me the page suggests that an atom must be a bound state of electron(s) and the nucleus. But let us not let terminology get in the way of physics: the emphasis I was trying to draw was to the fact that it is much, much harder to produce bound states of positrons and anti matter nuclei, than to just produce the nuclei themselves. Which is partly why last year's observation of "anti-hydrogen" was so exciting, when anti protons have been seen quite a while ago. (The fact it is electrically neutral only make it more so.)

Comment: @Willie. OK, if bound states including positrons is the criteria, those won't come out flying from a collider experiment :^)

Comment: @Hans: indeed, just thinking about making enough $\bar{\alpha}$, trapping them, and then throwing in enough positrons *and wait and see* makes me shudder at the effort that will involve.

Comment: @Willie; The first sentence in the definition of "ion" at wikipedia: "An ion is an atom or molecule in which the total number of electrons is not equal to the total number of protons, giving it a net positive or negative electrical charge." In order to conclude that a helium nuclei is not an atom, you have to conclude that it is also not an ion. But, for example, $H^+$, a hydrogen nuclei, is accepted as an ion. For example, see wikipedia definition of "hydron": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydron_%28chemistry%29 which is a "form of atomic hydrogen", and therefore an atom.

Comment: @Willie; Another reference for protons as atoms is the common phrase "atom smasher" for a proton accelerator. The better definition of an "atom" is "the smallest component of an element having the chemical properties of the element". The definition requiring that electrons be present is incorrect though common. See a complete description here: http://www.wereyouwondering.com/what-is-the-difference-between-atoms-and-molecules/

Comment: @Willie; Further search finds that the question of whether or not a nucleus is still an "atom" is argued with various opinions. Furthermore, it's something that is fairly obvious to the arguers. See: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=50333 Or maybe I should post the question and see how the vote goes.

Comment: @Carl: like I said, what I really wanted to point out is that there is a big difference in a collider experiment producing antimatter atomic nuclei and a (necessarily more complicated) experiment set-up producing anti-nuclei with positrons in bound states. This is nature; sometimes human language constructs aren't prescribed specifically enough to give consensus on the names for the edge cases (cf. Pluto several years ago). I can live with that.